# OpenGLES Sort Vertices to Draw Correct Shape with glDrawArrays

Tags: ios, opengl-es, 3d, vertices

I am working through an OpenGLES 2.0 tutorial where the author rendered a sphere with a texture on it. The sphere looks fine and was generated from a Wavefront OBJ file. The header he used looks like:

```
/*
created with obj2opengl.pl

source file    : sphere.obj
vertices       : 326
faces          : 648
normals        : 326
texture coords : 390

*/

unsigned int sphereNumVerts = 1944;

float sphereVerts [] = {
  // f 28/1/1 1/2/2 21/3/3
  7.6687116638888e-09, 0.466097, 0.115308018404908,
  -0.0265919923312883, 0.466097, 0.112200018404908,
  7.6687116638888e-09, 0.4795745, 1.84049079729628e-08,
  // f 21/4/3 1/2/2 2/5/4
  7.6687116638888e-09, 0.4795745, 1.84049079729628e-08,
  -0.0265919923312883, 0.466097, 0.112200018404908,
  -0.0517499923312883, 0.466097, 0.103043018404908,
  // f 21/6/3 2/5/4 3/7/5
  7.6687116638888e-09, 0.4795745, 1.84049079729628e-08,
  -0.0517499923312883, 0.466097, 0.103043018404908,
  -0.0741184923312883, 0.466097, 0.088331018404908,

 ... TRUNCATED ...

  // f 326/388/326 323/361/324 322/360/323
  7.6687116638888e-09, -0.5204255, 1.84049079729628e-08,
  0.0767490076687117, -0.490272, 0.152820018404908,
  0.109923007668712, -0.490272, 0.131001518404908,
  // f 326/389/326 324/362/325 323/361/324
  7.6687116638888e-09, -0.5204255, 1.84049079729628e-08,
  0.0394375076687117, -0.490272, 0.166400518404908,
  0.0767490076687117, -0.490272, 0.152820018404908,
  // f 326/390/326 325/363/299 324/362/325
  7.6687116638888e-09, -0.5204255, 1.84049079729628e-08,
  7.6687116638888e-09, -0.490272, 0.171010018404908,
  0.0394375076687117, -0.490272, 0.166400518404908,
};

float sphereNormals [] = {
  // f 28/1/1 1/2/2 21/3/3
  -0.00802618948953466, 0.967367838494132, 0.253248978930753,
  -0.0662268425664943, 0.967371914269316, 0.244551803932402,
  0, 1, -0,
  // f 21/4/3 1/2/2 2/5/4
  0, 1, -0,
  -0.0662268425664943, 0.967371914269316, 0.244551803932402,
  -0.120826192029109, 0.967370556337772, 0.222699883364347,
  // f 21/6/3 2/5/4 3/7/5
  0, 1, -0,
  -0.120826192029109, 0.967370556337772, 0.222699883364347,
  -0.168924852220773, 0.967372786949467, 0.18882342379009,
  // f 21/8/3 3/7/5 4/9/6

 ... TRUNCATED ...

  0, -1, -0,
  0.163004478217867, -0.939604578019474, 0.300953114364626,
  0.22801091084251, -0.939601478627697, 0.255264736885873,
  // f 326/389/326 324/362/325 323/361/324
  0, -1, -0,
  0.0891781381121659, -0.939606064036581, 0.330435627783284,
  0.163004478217867, -0.939604578019474, 0.300953114364626,
  // f 326/390/326 325/363/299 324/362/325
  0, -1, -0,
  0.0105903724426618, -0.939606044104724, 0.342094030777207,
  0.0891781381121659, -0.939606064036581, 0.330435627783284,
};

float sphereTexCoords [] = {
  // f 28/1/1 1/2/2 21/3/3
  0.000000, 0.925926,
  0.037037, 0.925926,
  0.000000, 1.000000,
  // f 21/4/3 1/2/2 2/5/4
  0.037037, 1.000000,
  0.037037, 0.925926,
  0.074074, 0.925926,
  // f 21/6/3 2/5/4 3/7/5
  0.074074, 1.000000,
  0.074074, 0.925926,
  0.111111, 0.925926,

 ... TRUNCATED ...

  // f 326/388/326 323/361/324 322/360/323
  0.888889, 0.037037,
  0.925926, 0.111111,
  0.888889, 0.111111,
  // f 326/389/326 324/362/325 323/361/324
  0.925926, 0.037037,
  0.962963, 0.111111,
  0.925926, 0.111111,
  // f 326/390/326 325/363/299 324/362/325
  0.962963, 0.037037,
  1.000000, 0.111111,
  0.962963, 0.111111,
};
```

I made my own object and I exported it to a header file using Cheetah3D and it looks like this:

```
// Headerfile *.h (generated by Cheetah3D)
//
// There are the following name conventions:
//  NAME            =name of the object in Cheetah3D. Caution!! Avoid giving two objects the same name
//  NAME_vertex     =float array which contains the vertex,normal and uvcoord data 
//  NAME_index      =int array which contains the polygon index data
//  NAME_vertexcount    =number of vertices
//  NAME_polygoncount   =number of triangles
//
// The vertex data is saved in the following format:
//  u0,v0,normalx0,normaly0,normalz0,x0,y0,z0
//  u1,v1,normalx1,normaly1,normalz1,x1,y1,z1
//  u2,v2,normalx2,normaly2,normalz2,x2,y2,z2
//  ...
// You can draw the mesh the following way:
//  glEnableClientState(GL_INDEX_ARRAY);
//  glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
//  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
//  glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
//  glInterleavedArrays(GL_T2F_N3F_V3F,0,NAME_vertex);
//  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,NAME_polygoncount*3,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,NAME_index);
//

#define Box_vertexcount     24
#define Box_polygoncount    12


float Box_vertex[Box_vertexcount][8]={
        {0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000, -0.15000, -0.15000, 0.15000},
        {0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000, -0.15000, 0.15000, 0.15000},
        {1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000, 0.15000, 0.15000, 0.15000},
        {1.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000, 0.15000, -0.15000, 0.15000},
        {0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000, 0.15000, -0.15000, -0.15000},
        {0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000, 0.15000, 0.15000, -0.15000},
        {1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000, -0.15000, 0.15000, -0.15000},
        {1.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000, -0.15000, -0.15000, -0.15000},
        {0.00000, 1.00000, -1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, -0.15000, -0.15000, -0.15000},
        {0.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, -0.15000, 0.15000, -0.15000},
        {1.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, -0.15000, 0.15000, 0.15000},
        {1.00000, 1.00000, -1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, -0.15000, -0.15000, 0.15000},
        {0.00000, 1.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.15000, -0.15000, 0.15000},
        {0.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.15000, 0.15000, 0.15000},
        {1.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.15000, 0.15000, -0.15000},
        {1.00000, 1.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.15000, -0.15000, -0.15000},
        {0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, -0.15000, 0.15000, 0.15000},
        {0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, -0.15000, 0.15000, -0.15000},
        {1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, 0.15000, 0.15000, -0.15000},
        {1.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, 0.15000, 0.15000, 0.15000},
        {0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000, 0.00000, -0.15000, -0.15000, -0.15000},
        {0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000, 0.00000, -0.15000, -0.15000, 0.15000},
        {1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000, 0.00000, 0.15000, -0.15000, 0.15000},
        {1.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000, 0.00000, 0.15000, -0.15000, -0.15000},
        };


int Box_index[Box_polygoncount][3]={
        {0, 1, 2},
        {2, 3, 0},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {6, 7, 4},
        {8, 9, 10},
        {10, 11, 8},
        {12, 13, 14},
        {14, 15, 12},
        {16, 17, 18},
        {18, 19, 16},
        {20, 21, 22},
        {22, 23, 20},
        };
```

I converted it to the same format as the example header file from the OBJ file so it looks like:

```
// sphere_3d.h Header File created from Cheetah 3d sphere File


unsigned int sphereNumVerts = 24;


float sphereTexCoords [] = {
       0.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 1.00000,
};


float sphereNormals [] = {
       0.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000,
       0.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000,
       0.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000,
       0.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000,
       0.00000, 0.00000, -1.00000,
       -1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000,
       -1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000,
       -1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000,
       -1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000,
       1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000,
       0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000,
       0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000,
       0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000,
       0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000,
       0.00000, -1.00000, 0.00000,
       0.00000, -1.00000, 0.00000,
       0.00000, -1.00000, 0.00000,
       0.00000, -1.00000, 0.00000,
};


float sphereVerts [] = {
       -0.15000, -0.15000, 0.15000,
       -0.15000, 0.15000, 0.15000,
       0.15000, 0.15000, 0.15000,
       0.15000, -0.15000, 0.15000,
       0.15000, -0.15000, -0.15000,
       0.15000, 0.15000, -0.15000,
       -0.15000, 0.15000, -0.15000,
       -0.15000, -0.15000, -0.15000,
       -0.15000, -0.15000, -0.15000,
       -0.15000, 0.15000, -0.15000,
       -0.15000, 0.15000, 0.15000,
       -0.15000, -0.15000, 0.15000,
       0.15000, -0.15000, 0.15000,
       0.15000, 0.15000, 0.15000,
       0.15000, 0.15000, -0.15000,
       0.15000, -0.15000, -0.15000,
       -0.15000, 0.15000, 0.15000,
       -0.15000, 0.15000, -0.15000,
       0.15000, 0.15000, -0.15000,
       0.15000, 0.15000, 0.15000,
       -0.15000, -0.15000, -0.15000,
       -0.15000, -0.15000, 0.15000,
       0.15000, -0.15000, 0.15000,
       0.15000, -0.15000, -0.15000,
};
```

I want to use glDrawArrays rather than glDrawElements so that I will not be using an index array. When I do so in my program by attempting to substite my custom object's header file instead of the example one in the example program, the shape generally ( somewhat ) looks like my substituted object by many of the triangles are off and not connected where they should be.

I know that the order in which my vertices are being passed to glDrawArrays is incorrect but I don't know why. How can I sort them so that they are in the order the glDrawArrays requires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason for not wanting to use glDrawElements? If you look at the Box_index array in your Cheetah3D header file, you'll see some vertices are used more than once, which means that to draw the same object using glDrawArrays you will have to duplicate some vertices (and therefore use more memory). Using the Box_index array you could draw your object with glDrawElements:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, Box_polygoncount * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, Box_index);
```

(note that if you have 0-256 vertices you should use bytes for indices, and shorts if you have between 257-65536)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I have actually done just that ( use glDrawElements ) with the Cheetah3D file. However, I want to do so with glDrawArrays as mostly a learning exercise. The same order of vertices used in the glDrawElements call does not look correct with glDrawArrays. I'm curious why not? How can I sort them so they make sense and look correct? Thanks!

Comment: You would have to place them in the order as described by the index array (Box_index).